# Highlight Intersect By Color

Tags: vba, excel, formatting

I'm working on some custom formatting, banded rows and columns and where they intersect, highlighting to a darker shade.

Two procedures working together.  The first (RangeBanding) works as intended, and bands the even rows and columns.

When I run the second (IntersectColor), things start to go sideways.  I'm having trouble nailing down the reference for the cells I want to change color.  It's probably right in front of me, but no matter the sequence of If/Else or Case or Intersect, I can't get the reference right.

I've commented out some of the direction I was working in previously.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
Sub RangeBanding()

Dim rw As Range
Dim col As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set rng = Range("TestRange")

'   For each row in range,if even band color
    For Each rw In rng.Rows
        If Not IsOdd(rw.Row) Then rw.Interior.Color = RGB(241, 241, 241)
    Next rw

'   For each column in range, if even band color
    For Each col In rng.Columns
        If Not IsOdd(col.Column) Then col.Interior.Color = RGB(241, 241, 241)
    Next col

End Sub

Sub IntersectColor()

    Set rng = Range("TestRange")

    For Each cell In rng
'   cell select to watch step in debug
        cell.Select
        On Error Resume Next
            If cell.Offset.Interior.Color = xlNone Then
                cell.Interior.Color = xlNone
            ElseIf (cell.Interior.Color = RGB(241, 241, 241)) And _ (cell.Offset(0, -1).Interior.Color = xlNone) Then
                cell.Interior.Color = RGB(241, 241, 241)
            ElseIf (cell.Interior.Color = RGB(241, 241, 241)) And _ (cell.Offset(-1, -1).Interior.Color = RGB(241, 241, 241)) Then
               cell.Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
            End If

            'Select Case cellcolor
                'Case Is = (ActiveCell.Interor.Color = RGB(241, 241, 241)) And (ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).Interior.Color = xlNone)
                 '   ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
            'End Select

    Next cell
End Sub

Function IsOdd(ByVal l As Long) As Boolean
    IsOdd = l Mod 2
End Function
```

Desired effect:
[Color intersect Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9xqQ.jpg)

Comment: Is it the case that if a cell is lightly shaded, and its neighbour is, then the neighbour should be shaded dark? Turn off the `On Error` to start with so you can see if there are any errors. If you're in column 1 you can't offset to the left so that will cause an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub RangeBanding()
    Dim itm As Range, isEven As Boolean, isXing As Boolean
    Dim clr1 As Long, clr2 As Long, clrW As Long, clr As Long

    clr1 = RGB(241, 241, 241)   'light
    clr2 = RGB(217, 217, 217)   'dark
    clrW = xlNone               'transparent (white)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each itm In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("TestRange").Cells
        With itm
            isEven = .Row Mod 2 = 0 Or .Column Mod 2 = 0
            isXing = .Row Mod 2 = 0 And .Column Mod 2 = 0
            clr = clrW
            Select Case True
                Case isXing: clr = clr2 'must be first in the select statement
                Case isEven: clr = clr1
            End Select
            .Interior.Color = clr
        End With
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.  The extra color was a nice touch; I updated it from white to "xlNone."  Everything went off without a hitch.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub RangeBanding()

Dim rw As Range
Dim col As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set rng = Range("TestRange")

'   For each row in range,if even band color
    For Each rw In rng.Rows
        If Not IsOdd(rw.Row) Then rw.Interior.Color = RGB(241, 241, 241)
    Next rw

'   For each column in range, if even band color
    For Each col In rng.Columns
        If Not IsOdd(col.Column) Then col.Interior.Color = RGB(241, 241, 241)
    Next col

    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        If Not IsOdd(cell.Column) And Not IsOdd(cell.Row) Then
            col.Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
        Next col
    End if

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

A pair of conditional formatting rules should take care of this.

```
With Range("TestRange")
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(NOT(MOD(ROW(), 2)),NOT(MOD(COLUMN(), 2)))")
        .Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
        .StopIfTrue = True
    End With
    With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=OR(NOT(MOD(ROW(), 2)),NOT(MOD(COLUMN(), 2)))")
        .Interior.Color = RGB(241, 241, 241)
        .StopIfTrue = True
    End With
End With
```

[image]